# Preventing overflow on date conversion

Tags: java, hive, hiveql

While using a date input, we created a value we thought would be very wrong: the 45th of February 2017 or "2017-02-45".
This resulted in adding the overflow of days into the next month and we ended with a March date.
Is there a way to check for these inconsistencies in dates inexpensively?
The current plan is convert string to date to text and compare with the original value.
The next is to create a Java UDF and use that to check as well as test format.

Comment: What does `adding the overflow of days into the next month` mean? Casting 2017-02-45 to a date will return a null.

Comment: Post your code. At least three date-time frameworks are commonly used, each with different behavior in this regard. And explain the connection to Apace Hive (so tagged).

Comment: What we are seeing is that 2017-02-45 turns into a date value of ~March 17th 2017. It is not a null value. Some research has it similar to DataFormat.setLenient(false).

Comment: @user1281598 If you mean [`java.text.DateFormat`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), that class is part of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Avoid `Date`, `Calendar`, `DateFormat` classes.

Comment: `setLenient(false)` in the old DateFormat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use modern java.time classes.

Catch `DateTimeParseException` thrown when parsing via `LocalDate` using either `ResolverStyle.STRICT` or `SMART`.

## Details

Depends on the date-time classes you are using.

The modern java.time classes parse using any of three modes known as [*resolver style*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html):

- [ResolverStyle.STRICT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT) (default)
- [ResolverStyle.SMART](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#SMART)
- [ResolverStyle.LENIENT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#LENIENT)

The default `STRICT` throws an [`java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) when parsing "2017-02-45".

```
LocalDate.parse( "2017-02-45" )
```

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-02-45' could not be parsed: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 45

Ditto for `SMART`, exception thrown.

Only `LENIENT` accepts the faulty input and adjusts.

> input: 2017-02-45
>
> output: 2017-03-17

See [this live code example in IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/h8uVN6) where we try each of the three modes.

```
String input = "2017-02-45" ;
System.out.println( "input: " + input ) ;

for( ResolverStyle rs : ResolverStyle.values() ) 
{
    try{
        System.out.println( "---------------" ) ;
        System.out.println( "Parsing with ResolverStyle: " + rs ) ;
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.withResolverStyle( rs ) ;
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
        System.out.println( "ld.toString(): " + ld ) ;
    } catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
        System.out.println( "Caught exception for ResolverStyle: " + rs ) ;
    }

}
```

```
input: 2017-02-45
---------------
Parsing with ResolverStyle: STRICT
Caught exception for ResolverStyle: STRICT
---------------
Parsing with ResolverStyle: SMART
Caught exception for ResolverStyle: SMART
---------------
Parsing with ResolverStyle: LENIENT
ld.toString(): 2017-03-17
```